# What is the method to prove $p\Rightarrow q \wedge r$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, solution-verification

I want to prove $p\Rightarrow q \wedge r$. If I prove $p \wedge q \Rightarrow r$ and $p \wedge r \Rightarrow q$ , will the proof be correct? If not then what is the method to do this kind of proofs?

Answer (score 1):

No. Notice that if $p$ is True and $q$ and $r$ are both False, then $(p \land q) \to r$ and $(p \land r) \to q$ are both True, but $p \to (q \land r)$ is False.

Typically, to prove a statement like $p \to (q \land r)$, you do a conditional proof: Assume $p$, and try to show $q \land r$ ... which is probably easiest done by proving $q$ and $r$ within that assumption.

However, it all depends on what proof system you are using, and also what statements are given to you as premises.

Comment: I am just a beginner in proofs. I suppose if we want to prove $p \Rightarrow q$ then we assume p to be true and we try to prove that if p is true then q must be true. Am i correct in thinking so? If yes, then there is no point talking about q and r being false.

Comment: @VarunSingh Yes, one way to prove $p \to q$ is to assume $p$ and try to prove $q$.  Likewise, one way to prove $q \to (q \land r)$ is to assume $p$, and to prove $q \land r$.  My comment about $q$ and $r$ being false and $p$ being true was to demonstrate that your way of trying to prove $p \to (q \land r)$ as suggested in your post does not work:  if $p$ is true and $q$ and $r$ are both false, then you can prove both $(p \land q) \to r$ and $(p \land r) \to q$ (since they are then both True),  but you cannot prove $(p \land q) \to r$ (because that is now False).

Comment: If q is false then how can we prove $p \wedge q \Rightarrow r$, considering that we need the assumption to be true in order to prove its implication true.

Comment: It’s exactly because the ‘if’ part is false that the whole conditional is true. Take a look at the truth-table for the conditional